# Eloquent request : column ID ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all rows of a table with Eloquent where the ID is not in an array `$ids`.

```
$product_deleteds = $category->products()->whereNotIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

I got this error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

The request produce is this one :

```
Select * 
from `products` 
inner join `products_categories` on `products_categories`.`id` = `products`.`product_category_id` 
where `products`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `products_categories`.`restaurant_id` = 1 
and `id` = 4 limit 1
```

I know I could make my request like this :

```
$product_deleteds = $category->products()->whereNotIn('products.id', $ids)->get();
```

But I don't want because the name of the table could change. I could to this too, but it seems to be a little tricky :

```
$product_deleteds = $category->products()->whereNotIn(Product::getTableName().'.id', $ids)->get();
```

Any help ?

Comment: If the table name is likely to change, then the `Product::getTableName()` approach is the one that I'd take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you couldn't do that:

```
$product_deleteds = $category->products()->whereNotIn(
   Product::getTableName() // no such method and definitely not static, unless you create one
.'.id', $ids)->get();
```

But you can do this in order to avoid hard-coding anything:

```
$relatedKey = $category->products()->getRelated()->getQualifiedKeyName();

$product_deleteds = $category->products()->whereNotIn($relatedKey, $ids)->get();
```

Comment: OKay. Nothing easier ? I was planning to create a "getTableName()" function or set the $table variable as static. What's your opinion ?

Comment: Well if you find it not easy enough, and would like to create a new method for something, that can be achieved easily with builtin methods, then I don't know :)