# Get only main columns in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to retrieve all data about a product belonging to a category belonging to a restaurant with Eloquent. So I'm doing this request :

```
$restaurant->products()->where((new Product())->getTable().'.id', $id)->first();
```

But this code is transformed in this request :

```
select * from `if_products` 
inner join `if_products_categories` on `if_products_categories`.`id` = `if_products`.`product_category_id` 
where `if_products`.`deleted_at` is null and `if_products_categories`.`restaurant_id` = '1' and `if_products`.`id` = '2' 
limit 1
```

So I'm retrieving all column from if_products and if_products_categories. And as both have a `name` column, I retrieve the name of the category here and not the name of category and not the name of the product.

As always, I could handle this with this :

```
[...]->first(array((new Product())->getTable().'.*'))
```

But it's so inconvenient... As in my previous question ([Eloquent request : column ID ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936104/eloquent-request-column-id-ambiguous)), I think Eloquent begin to be such a waste of time...

And you, how would you handle this ?

**Edit**

Here are some extra informations about my models :

```
class Restaurant extends Eloquent
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Product', 'ProductCategory');
    }

    public function productsCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductCategory');
    }
}

class ProductCategory extends Eloquent
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }

    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Restaurant');
    }
}

class Product extends Eloquent
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProductCategory', 'product_category_id');
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to get a product (ID 2) being sure that it belong to a restaurant (ID 1), that is why I pass by the restaurant model.

Comment: No Eloquent relation does this. Your question lacks basic info, so it's hard to help you. Anyway, by what you said I'm guessing it's `hasManyThrough`, so there will be `select table.* ...`. Next - What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want a product, then don't query the `$restaurant`.

Comment: I added extra informations (models). I well have a hasManyThrough relationship and I'm trying to get the product ID 2 being sure that it belongs to the restaurant ID 1.

Comment: OK, so with this relation you get `select products.*`, period. Then no problem and your code works as expected. You could use `Product::whereHas(..)->find($id)` instead, but the 1st solution looks better.

Comment: No, with the first portion of code, I get `select *`. And the second one works, but it's so unconvenient...

Comment: And how do you know that? And what framework version do you use?

Comment: I see it with Laravel Debugbar (`"barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "1.7.*"`) and I'm currently using Laravel 4.2.9 (`"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"`).

Comment: Well.. That's true, apparently it's a bug in `HasManyThrough` relation. It happens for each fetching method but `get` and `paginate`. So it requires a fix, and for now you can use only cumbersome method no 1 `get( columns )` or no 2.

Comment: OKay, I've make a pull request about this here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5821. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure of what you mean, but perhaps you are looking for this:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Eloquent {
    public function restaurant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Restaurant');
    }
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}

class Restaurant extends Eloquent {
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
$products = $restaurant->where(...condition...)
    ->categories()->where(...condition...)
    ->products()->get()
```

Comment: THank you for your respone, but I already have this in my Controller. See my edited question for more informations.

Comment: Btw this controller piece won't work, for it's completely wrong - you don't chain relations on the query builder.